# adding a parameter in all requests javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, struts-1

We have a application developed in Struts 1.x.  We are not using Ajax to POST/GET data from the server.

Earlier, this UI was serving data for only one customer, and now we are updating our server to provide data for all customers based on 'customer id'. The 'customer id' has to be passed in all requests to server and we need to achieve this with minimal changes.

Is there any smart way to add 'customer id' in all requests to server?  We don't want to have this parameter in the session or in cookies. This customer id will be output of a request, and all subsequent requests should have this customer id.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a 4 columns table in database and record customer id, ip, date and exp. date.

Comment: The question, as I read it, is 'how do ensure that a specific parameter is passed to the server?' Not 'how do I store parameters on the server?' I can't think of an interpretation of the question that is answered by your answer.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for answer, but my problem was how to pass parameter in all requests.

Comment: @Ram: you're welcome, but I didn't answer; I merely pointed out that I thought this answer failed to answer the question (giving mrash a chance to amend, or delete, as s/he thought appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by custom ajax method  ($.ajax method)

```
(function ($) {

var _ajax = $.ajax,

A = $.ajax = function(options) {

if (A.data) {

//TODO: the appending in here, i just don't feel like

writing all of this

}

return _ajax(options);

};

};

});
// and all your ajax calls will get that data

$.get({...})

$.post({...})
```

Comment: Hi as mentioned above, we are not using AJAX and we have hundreds of calls to server, so now refactoring to make use of AJAX will be lot of work, is it possible to do with plan javascript and struts 1.X